# Consecutively loading CustomViewControllers on command

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I want to load two Custom View Controllers consecutively (once Next button on first is pressed)

```
    let aVc: UIViewController = StartAlertViewVC()
    self.presentViewController(aVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code is from my main controller **View Controller**. 
This is how I call my first Custom View Controller (**StartAlertViewVC**).

On StartAlertViewVC.swift, I have a next button. (which just simply dismisses it)

```
@IBAction func Next(sender: AnyObject) {
    let selectedStartTime: String = startTimeLabel.text!
    self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Essentially, when the "Next" button is pressed on StartAlertViewVC, i want it to dismiss it and then load my second Custom View Controller (**EndAlertViewVC)**. On that controller, there is a button that says "Report!".

I want it to work something like this:

**ViewController.swift**

```
let aVc: UIViewController = StartAlertViewVC()
self.presentViewController(aVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

// If "next" button is pressed, then load EndAlertViewVC

let eVc: UIViewController = EndAlertViewVC()
self.presentViewController(aVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

// If "report!" button is pressed, then load ...

segue.performSegueWithIdentifier("report", sender: AnyObject?())
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, that's what the `completion` handler is for, isn't it?

Comment: May I have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. Here's one simple solution:

Knowing that `viewWillAppear` will be called on `ViewController` when the modally presented AlertVC's are dismissed...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var shouldPresentEndAlertVC = false

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // This bool is set to true only when the StartAlertVC is presented
    if shouldPresentEndAlertVC == true {

        let eVc: UIViewController = EndAlertViewVC()
        self.presentViewController(eVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        shouldPresentEndAlertVC = false
    }

}

func showStartAlertController(){
    let aVc: UIViewController = StartAlertViewVC()
    self.presentViewController(aVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    shouldPresentEndAlertVC = true
}
}
```

**Another solution** would be to let `ViewController` handle the dismissal of the two alertVC's, (using custom delegation on your alertVC's, communicating back to `ViewController`)

This delegate method on `ViewController` could then look like this

```
func startAlertVCShouldDismiss(alertVC : StartAlertViewVC)
{
    alertVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

        let eVc: UIViewController = EndAlertViewVC()
        self.presentViewController(eVc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
}
```